# Extracting multiple substrings and returning a value for each substring

Tags: r

I'd like to find an elegant approach:

1. to extract multiple substrings from each row in df1
2. store the multiple substrings for each row as a vector or list
3. return a value for each row vector in df1

I have two data frames:

```
n = c("Canada and USA", "USA and Mexico", "Canada and Mexico")
df1 = data.frame(n)

m = c("Canada", "USA", "Mexico")
o = c(5, 8, 7)
df2= data.frame(m, o)
```

My resulting data frame would look like:

```
n = c("Canada and USA", "USA and Mexico", "Canada and Mexico")
p = c(13, 15, 12)
df3 = data.frame(n, p)
```

where the values of vector 'p', is the sum of elements of vector 'o' that correspond to vector 'n'.

Note: I am only looking for a method, so I may work on this problem.

Currently, I am stuck on using lapply and regex to extract the multiple substrings from df1 and don't know how to store the substrings, whether in a list or another data frame.

Any thoughts and advice on how to approach the problem will be most appreciated, as I would like to take my time to fully understand the mechanics behind the solution to this problem.

Thank you in advance!

Edited: for formatting

Comment: try `strsplit(as.character(df1$n), " and ")`

Comment: Are your result sums `p` right? I am not getting those values (not in that order).

Comment: @Pieca, the strsplit is a nice idea, but may not be helpful if df1 may contain additional filler words in the string.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, P is the result sums of O for the substring combination :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following will do what you want.
First, create an index matrix, with the indices of the matches of `df2$m`. Then use the index matrix to sum the values in `df2$o`.

```
inx <- sapply(df2$m, function(s) grep(s, df1$n))
df4 <- data.frame(n, p = apply(inx, 2, function(i) sum(df2$o[i])))

df4
#                  n  p
#1    Canada and USA 12
#2    USA and Mexico 13
#3 Canada and Mexico 15
```

Comment: does the 's' in grep(s, df1$n) represent the pattern variable?

Comment: @Runner Yes, it does. The instruction reads *apply to each element `s` of the vector `df2$m` the function `grep(etc)`*. I chose `s` because it is a string, maybe `p` for pattern would have been better.

Comment: the sapply function takes on an error where the argument 'pattern' has length >1. Am i missing on a step here or a library file? sorry, I'm a little new to R.

Comment: @Runner `sapply` passes exactly one element of the vector `df2$m` to the function, how are you getting patterns with length > 1? Can you post the code you are running and the error message, please?

Comment: @RuiBarradas-  'inx <-sapply(df2$m, function(s) grep(s, df1$n))'   and the error message: 'Warning messages:
1: In base::grep(pattern = pattern, x = x, ignore.case = ignore.case,  :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In base::grep(pattern = pattern, x = x, ignore.case = ignore.case,  :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In base::grep(pattern = pattern, x = x, ignore.case = ignore.case,  :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used'

Comment: Solution works perfectly now, the fault was on my end where grep was masked from base and was using regexPipes. After removing regexPipes and rerunning your solution, it worked admirably! thank you